# Need advice on model design using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and base types

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-modeling, entity-framework-4.1

I need some advice on part of my model I am designing. As you can see in my Rfi entity, I have a collection of BaseImpact types. There will be several types of impacts that can be added to that collection. Each impact type has its own properties. As an example I created a Cost Impact and a Schedule Impact. Now, these are not very different, but you get the idea. I am trying to figure out how I can use this same type of model and then add the mappings / relationships to the database. I'd really like the BaseImpact to be abstract, but I may need it to be in the DB, but I am not usre.

```
    public class Rfi
        {
            public ICollection<BaseImpact> Impacts { get; set; }
        }

        public class BaseImpact : BaseEntity
        {
            #region Navigation
            public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
            #endregion
        }

        public class CostImapct: BaseImpact
        {
            public decimal Cost { get; set; }

        }
        public class ScheduleImpact: BaseImpact
        {
            public int days { get; set; }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx&rct=j&q=code%20first%20inheritance&ei=52_aTfKWAYaRgQeuwoxY&usg=AFQjCNH3v5h6lp1Ml0gm-P-2xW7gdlUQbA&sig2=dXx5EwcRzr0usaQ6tkYM2w&cad=rja) [series](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCUQFjAC&url=http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx&rct=j&q=code%20first%20inheritance&ei=52_aTfKWAYaRgQeuwoxY&usg=AFQjCNH0zSJoCLMBHpyU0aSqjQSJZGxvVQ&sig2=Izm-gMVtDs86j5JtqbN0Rg&cad=rja) of [posts](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CB8QFjAB&url=http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx&rct=j&q=code%20first%20inheritance&ei=52_aTfKWAYaRgQeuwoxY&usg=AFQjCNEViBX_mIGDlIEOiQwTZMCfYpACQw&sig2=7CSpIlka3RkIIiM-mZ2C7Q&cad=rja) on different options for modeling inheritance hierarchies in EF Code First.

Comment: I had ran accross those posts before and totally didn;t think about that! this is exactly what I was looking for!